# Unable to access formdata from Axios POST to Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask api that I am starting and I am sending a post generated by AXIOS.post:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "A REEALLY REALLY LONG KEY"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mysql+pymysql://ppsadmin:@localhost/ppsportal"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db  = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.route("/login")
def login():            
    data = request.form
    print(data)
    return json.dumps({"success":True})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When I run this code Flask returns a 405 error and I am unable to access the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

I forgot to wrap the app in CORS.